# Strange behaviour of location block access control

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm using Nginx with a `location` block similar to this:

```
location /securelocation {
    allow MY_IP;
    deny all;
}
```

and at first glance, this appears to work fine. From not `MY_IP`:

- accessing `domain.com/securelocation` returns `403 Forbidden`
- accessing `domain.com/securelocation/` returns `403 Forbidden`

but this breaks down when accessing any subfolders or files. From not `MY_IP`:

- accessing `domain.com/securelocation/index.html` returns `200 OK` and the contents of the file

Using Nginx's built-in basic auth fails in the same way(obviously with `401` instead of `403`), despite [this page on nginx.com](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access-auth-basic/) detailing the setup of basic auth using the exact same `location` block as above.

I'm guessing the fix to this involves regex of some sort, which I'm not great at. What would a location block need to look like for it to include the paths

- `/securelocation`
- `/securelocation/`
- `/securelocation/index.html`

and ***any*** other combination of subfolders and files.

And *why on earth* would Nginx documentation detail this setup when it is totally useless in offering any security?

Comment: I think you are looking for `location ~* /securelocation {`

Comment: Yes, that’s working great, I thought it’d be simple! In reference to the last part of my question, why would the Nginx docs (plus countless other tutorials I’ve found) show it this way? Even the `default` site of Nginx uses a location block without `~*` for its `try_files` directive. I can’t think of a reason for this, but if there is one, I’m open.

Comment: Sorry, I take that back! PHP files are now echoing their contents unprocessed as plain text now! Once again, I’m using the settings from the `default` site, which is a location block with `~ \.php$`, to send php files to `php-fpm`